# Grunt + require.js config for a simple website

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, requirejs, gruntjs

I have the following simple structure for my website:

```
src
  js
    core.js
    main.js
  lib
    jquery-1.8.2.js
    require-2.1.1.js
    require-text.js
  templates
    1.html
    2.html
  index.html
build
```

I want all js+lib files to be compiled into one build/js/main.js file and other files just to be copied to build folder. How to write grunt.js config for this task? It seems I should use grunt-contrib-require..

The second question is how to compile 1.html and 2.html (I use require text! plugin) into one line for each and include theese lines to build/js/main.js? This case there should be only two files into build folder - index.html and main.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Grunt Website offers a very good tutorial to get you started, this is what you will need:

- [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) - To put files together in one
- [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) - To copy files to your "build" folder
- [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) - To use the compiled js file in your html

I am not sure how to put those html files together though, feels weird to do that but maybe you can find a plugin for it.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) and see if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Gruntfile.js` should reside at the root of the directory i.e `ls should show src/ build/ Gruntfile.js`

Contents of `` `Gruntfile.js `` specific for your requirements:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {

            js: {
                src: [
                    'src/js/*', 'src/lib/*'
                ],
                dest: 'build/js/combined.js'
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            js: {
                files: {
                    'build/js/main.js': ['build/js/combined.js']
                }
            }
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:js', 'uglify:js']);
};
```

I don't think `require-js` to be used here. `Require-js` is helpful when you need to load your `js scripts` in a specific order. If that being the case add the below code in your `Gruntfile.js` just below `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),` line

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "path/to/base",
      mainConfigFile: "path/to/config.js",
      name: "path/to/almond", // assumes a production build using almond
      out: "path/to/optimized.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding [grunt-require](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-require) to the list that luschn put together. It uses r.js, has lots of options, and is pretty darn nice.